# react-navigation + redux When I press Android back button. App is killed not backward action

Tags: android, redux, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation and redux together.

The problem is, after building the android version, I press the back button of the android actual device (Samsung Galaxy 8, etc ..) and the app will exit without going backward.

However, in the android emulator, when I click the back button, it grabs the event and works backwards.

this is my index.js code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    BackHandler,
    AsyncStorage,
} from "react-native";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
    addNavigationHelpers,
    NavigationActions,
} from "react-navigation";

import NavigationStack from "./navigationStack";
import { login } from '../actions/actionCreator';
import * as settings from '../config/settings';


class AppNavigation extends Component {

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        // 안드로이드 백 버튼 인식
        BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);

        // 로컬스토리지 유저정보 유효성을 체크합니다.
        let user_info = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_info');

        if (user_info) {
            user_info = JSON.parse(user_info);

            let api_uri = settings.base_uri + "member/profile/"
            let request = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Token ' + user_info.key
                }
            }
            console.log('index is mounted');

            fetch(api_uri, request)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json()
                })
                .then((responseData) => {

                    if (responseData.email) {
                        console.log('pass user_info');
                        this.props.login();
                    } else {
                        console.log('remove user_info');
                        AsyncStorage.removeItem('user_info')
                    }
                    return responseData;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        } else {
            console.log('user is not logined');
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // 안드로이드 백버튼 listener 해제
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackPress.bind(this));
    }

    onBackPress = () => {
        const { dispatch, navigationState } = this.props;
        dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
        console.log('press android back6', navigationState.stateForLoggedIn.index)
        if (navigationState.stateForLoggedIn.index === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true
    };

    render() {
        const { navigationState, dispatch } = this.props;
        const state = navigationState.stateForLoggedIn
        return (
            <NavigationStack navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state })}/>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.loginReducer.isLoggedIn,
        navigationState: state.navigationReducer
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return Object.assign({ dispatch: dispatch }, bindActionCreators({ login: login }, dispatch ));
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppNavigation);
```

this is my package.json

```
{
"name": "*****",
"version": "****",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-moment": "^0.6.9",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.18.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.0.20",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "0.0.24",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
},
"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/luxlabUser/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'"
}
```

Comment: the problem must be on your `onBackPress` function. just try adding `return true;` before any statement on that function and see if it stops the app from exiting.

Comment: @InusSaha I try to typing just return true In onBackPress function. but when i press back button, The application changes to the background state.

Comment: what do you mean by background state? do you mean application exited?

Comment: @InusSaha Yes, It's means app exit.

Comment: @InusSaha I want go back screen not app exit.

Comment: try `return false;` and tell me. it should not exit the app now.

Comment: @InusSaha  It's same result. App exit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173610/discussion-between-inus-saha-and-byunghyun-park).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a react-navigation issue.
It was a problem to always return exitApp () on back press with react-native bug.
I had to modify the module file in the same way as the link below.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3223